# pylint warning E1101 "instance of 'object' has no replace member"

Tags: python, pylint

This is my code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self):

        self._data = {
            'some_value': string_value
        }

    def get_value(self):
        return self._data['some_value'].replace('"', '')
```

So I just want to return value with " character deleted. String value has type class 'str'. But now I always get pylint E1101 warning "instance of 'object' has no replace member". Why does it appear and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of pylint? I'm not geting that error.

Comment: Is `string_value` an actual string literal? Otherwise, depending on how much work the linter is doing, it may not be able to confirm the type is a `str` or an object that otherwise supports `.replace`...